# How to create music instrument strings in Android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create UI for a music instrument with strings. Can somebody direct me to what kind of controls be used in displaying UI with strings?

I want to give user the option to select the note on the music instrument.

Thanks

Comment: kindly elaborate your query, i have few of the apps line tuners so i would be easy for me to help you out

Comment: @FattiKhan: Updated. Basically I want user to select notes on the instrument.

Comment: I'd use a **ListView**. Each row containing a "string" picture. Or a TableLayout, a **GridView**, a GridLayout, ... you choose!

Comment: I may be weird, but if you have a set amount of strings and don't want scrolling I would just use a LinearLayout with simple views/weights to get what I wanted... If you don't want scrolling.

Comment: Probably, **you want scrolling**, in order to use **higher and lower notes**.

Comment: @DerGolem Yea that makes more sense, poor thinking on my part :P

Comment: @zgc7009 No matter... maybe you're not a musician ;)

Comment: @DerGolem You caught me!

Comment: Nice reference image: http://www.guitarbunny.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guitar_strings_by_attackment-d622sls.jpg